# Github set up private repository contributor error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: github, repository, private, git-clone

I'm new using Github. And today I try to contribute to a private repository(which I am already added as contributor) and set up connections in terminal using:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:myusername/EFIapi.git
```

But it returns an error as below:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: Problem solved by using the same code on Mac. Previously using windows, and wouldn't go through. Don't know why.... Anyone has idea why windows cannot handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using the same code on Mac. Previously using windows, and wouldn't go through. Don't know why.... Anyone has idea why windows cannot handle this?